# How can use Try/Catch in python

Tags: python

I want use try catch in Python but python give me an error what's can I do?

this is my code

```
try:
    input('enter your number');
catch:
    print('please give integer');
```

Comment: use `except` instead of `catch`

Comment: Try [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except)

Comment: `except` is mostly explained using the words "catch exceptions" in the docs and hence I guess you used the word `catch` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try/catch in python is try/except.

you can use try/except like this:

```
try:
   input('enter your number');
except expression:
   print('please give integer');
```

Comment: What is the expression here?

Comment: nice semi comma use there :)

Answer (score 4):

```
try: 
    int(input('enter your number')); 
except ValueError: 
    print('please give integer');
```

Use [handling-exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use following alternative for your use case :**

```
try:
    input_ = int(input('enter your number'))
except:
    print('please give integer')
    exit() #if you want to exit if exception raised
#If no exception raised, execution continues from here
print(input_)
```