# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' while using None

Tags: python

```
rating = input("")

if (rating == None):
    print("Please input a rating")

else:
    rating = int(rating)
    if (rating > 8):
        print("this album is amazing")
    else:
        print("this album is ok")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 24' in <cell line: 3>()
      4     print("Please input a rating")
      6 else:
----> 7     rating = int(rating)
      8     if (rating > 8):
      9         print("this album is amazing")

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

While trying to use "None" to identify a blank space left on the input, I got this message error. Any tips?

Comment: Your string is just the empty string `''`. You don't need to check against `None` but rather against `''`.

Comment: Tip: learn what kinds of values the `input` function can return.

Comment: Why don't you check whether the string is number or not?

Comment: *input()* will return a string. It may be an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Try this code without writing anything :

```
print(type(input()))
```

The program prints :

```
<class 'str'>
```

Because the function input() returns an empty string when you write nothing.
You should try this condition instead :

```
if (rating == ''):
    print("Please input a rating")
```

Also, you can use Python's internal mechanism that treats `None` objects and empty strings as `False`. This will now work for both situations:

```
if not rating:
  print("Please input a rating")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use a `try-except` block to handle any kind of error, be it a space or string as input from user. Read more on [How can use Try/Catch in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441958/how-can-use-try-catch-in-python/52442226)

Try this..

```
rating = input("Enter the rating: ")

while True:
    try:
        rating = int(rating)
        if (rating > 8):
            print("this album is amazing")
            break
        else:
            print("this album is ok")
            break
    except:
        rating = input("Enter the rating: ")
```

Comment: The principle of your suggestion is sound although if the user does not enter an integer, the program will prompt for further input and then terminate

Comment: Modified the code..Thanks for correcting..