# How to set a looped pd.read_excel to skip if an error returns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, operating-system, glob

I have some code set up to read specific data from every single xlsx file in a folder. However, the excels use two different naming conventions for the sheet I want (for example: Titlepage and Title Page). My current code is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import glob
import os

directory = 'file path'
files = os.listdir(directory)
list_of_dfs = []
```

Start of loop

```
os.chdir('file path')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel (file)
    df = df.T
    df = df.iloc[[1],:24]
    list_of_dfs.append(df)
```

End of loop

```
data_combined = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
data_combined.to_excel ('file path/output.xlsx', index=False)
```

I am thinking of having the loop above twice, once for Title Page, and once for Titlepage. However, the code will error if it cannot find the sheet name specific. Is there anyway to tell python to move to the next xlsx file if no such sheet name is found?

Edit:

I used the code below to make this work.

```
os.chdir("file path")
for file in files:
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel (file, sheet_name= 'Titlepage')
        df = df.T
        df = df.iloc[[1],:24]
        list_of_dfs.append(df)
    except:
        pass

for file in files:
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel (file, sheet_name= 'Title Page')
        df = df.T
        df = df.iloc[[1],:24]
        list_of_dfs.append(df)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can use Try/Catch in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441958/how-can-use-try-catch-in-python)

Comment: That solution is very close. I ended up using try: - my loop - except: pass to make it work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that helped, just make sure to follow one best practice: Don't use a bare `except` clause; if a missing sheet throws a specific error, include that in the except so that if another error happens concurrently, you don't bury under the blanket except clause